# How to abort function RunToPosition - AccelStepper / Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have prepared short testing code to control stepper motor by Serial Port (using AccelStepper library). The code use three commands M - to move motor to defined possition, H - to abort operation and P - to check current motor step possition. Each commends have to be finished with "#". So when I write M500# means that motor will start move until achieve possition 500. **My problem / question is how to abort this operation???** Serial port is blocked until RunToPosiotion function finish.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <MultiStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(AccelStepper::HALF4WIRE, 4, 5, 6, 7);
String MyString;
String Command;
int Value;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(400);
  stepper.setAcceleration(600);
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(100);
  }

void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
        if (inChar == '#') {
            SerialCommand(MyString);
            MyString = "";
        }
        else {
            MyString += inChar;
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    }

void SerialCommand(String ASCOM_Command) {
    Command = String(ASCOM_Command.charAt(0));
    String Txt_Value = ASCOM_Command.substring(1);
    Value = Txt_Value.toInt();

    /*Commands, an example: M500# - start motor to move until get  500 position 
    P - check actual focuser position
    M - Move to specific position called by client application
    H - Halt / Abort
    */
    switch (ASCOM_Command.charAt(0))    {

    case 'P':
        Serial.println(stepper.currentPosition()); 
        break;

    case 'M':
        stepper.moveTo(Value);
        stepper.runToPosition();
        break;
    case 'H':
        stepper.stop();
        Serial.println("H#");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the accelstepper doc and follow the hint for runtoPosition:

```
    Dont use this in event loops, since it blocks.
```

Have a look at `run()`  instead:

Keep loop() fast and simply call run() every time.